# Why is gradle build making an empty jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Whenever I call gradle build publish the jar it creates does not consist of the classes and results in only consisting of the manifest and I cannot determine how to fix this issue.

build.gradle:

```
defaultTasks 'assemble'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(":projectA")

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12',
            'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}

jar {
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class' : 'a.b.c.d.e.f.aClass'
    }
    destinationDir = buildDir
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/configs"
        }
    }
}
```

structure:

```
project
|_libs
      |_utilities.jar
|_src
    |_main
          |_java
                |_a/b/c/d/e/f
                             |_aClass.java
                             |_bClass.java
```